# Library to use for event extraction from text?

Tags: nlp

My project is to extract events automatically from a given text. The events can be written specifically, or just mentioned in a sentence, or not be there at all.

What is the library or technique that I should use for this? I tried the Stanford NER demo, but it gave bad results.  I have enough time to explore and learn a library, so complexity is not a problem.  Accuracy is a priority.

Comment: According to your favourite language, you might want to have a look at NLTK (python) or OpenNLP (Java). However, you'll still have to work a little, event extraction is not easy at all.

Comment: You can train Stanford NER yourself btw

Comment: Now with chatgpt, this is trivial. Just prompt it and ask it to output in json

Answer (score 0):

The task itself is a complex one, it is still not solve now(2018). But recently a very useful python library for nlp is emerging. It is [Spacy](https://spacy.io/), this lib has a relative higher performance than its competitors. With the library you can do things like  tokenize，POS tagging，NER and sentence similarity。But you still need to utilize these features and extract events based on your specific rule.

Deeplearning may also be a way to try, but even though it works fine on other nlp tasks, it is still immature on event extraction.